Rebind VR (controller) default input controls for custom wheelchair mechanic?
I am trying to reconfigure the basic controller inputs for a VR demo I'm making, where the main character is in a wheelchair.
I have the XR toolkits installed and have the basic controls working fine (hands, grip, etc.) - and I can move around using the thumbsticks too (using default left/right/strafe etc).
But what I would like to do is make 'Up' on the leftThumbStick rotate (clockwise) or, equally, 'Up' on rightThumbStick rotate (anti-clockwise) and if both are pressed 'Up' then actually Move forwards (and all of this in reverse for 'Down') - Y'know, like how a wheelchair moves ;)
I have been playing around with the XRI Default Input Actions (for locomotion and turn) - but can't figure out how to get 'in' to these default settings so that I can rebind 'left = rotate' and/or 'up' = forwards (for example using a Modified Binding).
Turn and Move currently use the Primary2DAxis Actions (for both left & right hands):
Turn:
Binding Path: Primary2DAxis
Use in control scheme: Noncontinuous Move
Interactions
Sector
Directions East, West
Sweep Behaviour Allow reentry
Sector
Directions South
Sweep Behaviour Disallow reentry
Move:
Binding Path: Primary2DAxis
Use in control scheme: Continuous Move
Interactions (none)
Processors (Stick deadlines set to default min 0.125 / max 0.925)
-
Essentially, I can't access the details below 'Thumbstick' in the binding path from the default Primary2Daxis (and really don't want to write a new script for 'everything' to do with all VR controls, just to switch out these two uses).
Thanks.
Nelson.

bind to the thumbstick and listen for the Y value of both, then just handle forward movement of the wheelchair based on the Y value, if y is negative then move forward, if positive then move backwards.
pseudo code:
wheelChair = wheelchairTransformer;
leftStickY = leftThumbstick.y
rightStickY = rightThumbstick.y

// apply movement or rotation
if(leftStickY < 0 && rightStickY < 0){
  apply forward velocity or movement to wheelChair 
} else if(leftStickY > 0 && rightStickY > 0){
  apply backwards velocity or movement to wheelChair 
} else if(leftStickY < 0 && rightStickY > 0){
  apply clockwise y rotation to wheelchair (where Y would be the up axis)
  // TODO: you could also add movement / velocity by calculating the difference / ration of leftStickY  and rightStickY 
} else if(leftStickY > 0 && rightStickY < 0){
  apply counter-clockwise y rotation to wheelchair (where Y would be the up axis)
  // TODO: you could also add movement / velocity by calculating the difference / ration of leftStickY  and rightStickY 
}

